npm install specific version of dependency inside dependency
This project uses next@13.5.6 and next-drupal@1.6.0.
package.json
"dependencies": {
  "next": "^13",
  "next-drupal": "^1.6.0",
}  

The dependency next@13 has a vulnerability that is fixed in next@14.
So I fixed with npm install next@14.2.3.
package.json
"dependencies": {
  "next": "^14.2.3",
  "next-drupal": "^1.6.0",
}  

However, running npm audit fix shows that next-drupal also uses next@13 as a dependency inside its own node modules node_modules/next-drupal/node_modules/next.
$ npm audit fix
next  >=13.4.0 <14.1.1
Severity: high
Next.js Server-Side Request Forgery in Server Actions - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fr5h-rqp8-mj6g
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/next-drupal/node_modules/next

Looking node_modules/next-drupal/node_modules/next inside package-lock.json I find the same next@13 that I need to update to 14.
package-lock.json
"node_modules/next-drupal/node_modules/next": {
      "version": "13.5.6",
     (more code)
}

What I pretend is to address the vulnerability of next@13 updating to 14. What is the correct way to achieve this?

From this next-drupal 1.6 npm package works with next 14, but has 13 as a dependency, triggering high vulnerability #759 I learned how to override the dependency of a dependency.
First, I had to add an override object in package.json.
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^14.2.3",
    "next-drupal": "^1.6.0",
    ...
  },
  "overrides": {
    "next-drupal": {
      "next": "$next"
    }
  }

Second, I had to delete node_modules and package-lock.json, before running npm install.
Finally, with npm list next I could verify that the module is overridden with the desired dependency.
├─┬ next-auth@4.24.5
│ └── next@14.2.3 deduped
├─┬ next-drupal@1.6.0 overridden
│ └── next@14.2.3 deduped
├─┬ next-i18next@15.2.0
│ └── next@14.2.3 deduped
└── next@14.2.3

